# Какую нагрузку сможет выдержать c# net core реализация?

Tags: c#, unity3d, asp.net-core, tcp

Есть машина Debian 9, 1,5Ghz, 1GbRam, Google Cloud Platform
Есть крайне простой "Сервер" вещатель - C# Net.Core 2.1.

В опреративой памяти держит список клиентов и комнат.
И при получении сообщения, просто отсылает другим по комнате.

Сообщения 1 килобайт сырых байтов, tcp/udp пакеты.

Вопрос: Сколько клиентов сможет без проседаний держать одна такая машина?
Надеюсь ответят кто на практике попробовал.

**UDP:** Я осознаю что кажется что вопрос не совсем конкретный, в плане того что никто не знает какой код у приложения. Но тут в вопросе уточнение, я не про законченный продукт а просто приложение по типу "принял сообщение, отправил остальным по комнате". Предпологал что в ответе напишут что у нас было такое-то приложение и выдерживало столько-то.

**UDP2** "держать" - одновременно, частота - реалтайм.

Comment: производительность проги сильно зависит от прямоты рук автора, от наличия БД, от используемых алгоритмов, от требований в концу концов к серверу и ПО, от пропускного канала,от частоты процессора и прочих факторов. Потому если кто то и напишет, что делал подобное, то это вам ничего абсолютно не даст, вам надо полюбому тестировать саш сервер на нагрузку самостоятельно

Comment: Уточните термин "держать". В течение долгого времени подключаться/отключаться могут миллионы клиентов. Может вы имеете в виду _одновременно_? А как часто они будут посылать/принимать данные: раз в сутки или несколько раз в секунду?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от качества кода и того подобного... В общем, на вопрос нельзя дать однозначный ответ и все будет гаданием на кофейной гуще.

Нужно провести нагрузочное тестирование с 1 клиентом и скажем с 10, а потом посмотреть на сколько % будет загружен сервер.

Если на 10%, то не сложно будет догадаться, что сервер сможет держать ~100 клиентов.

Comment: Ну, зависимость не обязательно линейная. Для нагрузочного тестирования лучше грузить сервер именно той нагрузкой (или большей), которая ожидается в проде.